# Q_DECL_EXPORT and Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS in shared library

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries, dllexport

While I was working on a small shared library, in which I'm using enums as flags, as usual, and as I'm using Qt, I'm using the `Q_DECLARE_FLAGS`, `Q_FLAG` and the `Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS` macros. Now I've been wondering, as normally the `Q_DECL_EXPORT` macro has to be put in front of every class/function that should be exported from the shared library, what about inline functions fully defined in a public header file, to be used by the user, like `Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS` does? Is it needed to put the export macro there too?

Comment: No, as the operators will be inlined. http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qflags.h.html#_M/Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS